# Changing rootviews view type in an iOS app

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, nib

While creating a navigation based application, it automatically creates a root view controller which subclasses `UITableViewController`, but in `MainWindow.xib` as you know I can't see a `UITableView` is placed under root view controller but we drag and drop a table view there. Can we simply drag and drop a `UIView` instead of a `UITableView` and change the root view controller class to sublass a `uiview` instead of `UITableView` and change its methods?

Or I must drag a `UITableView` in IB for the root view controller? I am a beginner and I do not want to make complicated things so what is the simplest way of using a `UIView` as a root. If thats not simple I will stick with the table view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can change. You just need to change some bindings in inteface builder and change rootViewController's superclass to UIViewController instead of UITableViewController.

**UPDATE**

First open the rootViewController.xib and delete the tableiew from there and drag-n-drop a UIView. Bind that View to view property in file-owner. Change superclass of rootViewController from UITableViewController to UIViewController. That's it.

Here are the screenshots.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks! now it works but when I open mainwinwdow.xib and look under rootvieew controller I cant see my new view object, I will set and add navigation items from there, and navigationcontrol toolbar. how can i do that

Comment: the new view object will not be there it is in rootViewController xib. You are not understanding the concept.If you want to add navigation items. you need to add through code in rootViewController's class.

Comment: tnx yes i do not understand the concept, if I didnt change it from uitable to uiview I was able to add from mainwindow.xib but now I cant, what is the reason? and why I can see that view in mainwindow.xib?

Comment: also I noticed when I use IB to to design my view, the navigation item and toolbar disaappered, I put them under vievDidlod method.

Comment: Well when you design your view from IB. I'll tell you the secret. Suppose the view you are going to create will be pushed by navigation controller. so make height of that view to 416. 480 - 20(status bar)-44(navigation bar). Also to change height you need to remove status bar from view by changing it's property. This way you will exactly same output you have designed.

Comment: tnx. and what about that there is still a tableview under mainwindow.xib which is not used anymore?

Comment: where is tableView in main window.? you should not put any tableView there. The thing works like this you have a navigation controller which contains a view controller. So in navigation based template that view controller's class is automatically assigned as rootView Controller and the nib name is also assigned to that view controller.That view Controller actually does not contain any view. That nib which is assigned to that view controller is holds the actual view. Hope you understand.